# Calling a Python function from another file and using the DF of that function

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a file called Pre_processing_File.py. This file pre-processes a text file (it works perfectly).

What I'm doing now is I have a separate .py file called naming.py.
In the naming.py file I want to call the function in the Pre_processing_File.py and then save the preprocessed file in an excel format. (See current code below)

```
import pandas as pd


def naming():
    import Pre_Processing_File
    from Pre_Processing_File import pre_Processing
    
    DormantAcc = pre_Processing(dir1,dir2)
    
naming()
```

**Pre_Processing File** - I have left most of the pre-processing code out. This script opens a GUI, takes in 2 input files dir1 and dir 2 and esentially compares them

```
from tkinter import *
  
# import filedialog module
from tkinter import filedialog

def pre_Processing(dir1,dir2):
    
    
    ## Import Libraries
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from pandas import DataFrame
    
    
    ######################################################################################################################
    ######################################################################################################################
    ## Read in the single long column, and then form a group indicator by seeing where the value is '[User]'. Then separate the 
    ## column labels and values, with a str.split and join back to your DataFrame. Finally pivot to your desired shape.
    
    userListing_DF = pd.read_csv(dir1, sep='\n', header=None)

    userListing_DF['Group'] = userListing_DF[0].eq('[User]').cumsum()
    userListing_DF = userListing_DF[userListing_DF[0].ne('[User]')]  # No longer need these rows

    userListing_DF = pd.concat([userListing_DF, userListing_DF[0].str.split('=', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'col', 1: 'val'})],
                               axis=1)

    userListing_DF = userListing_DF.pivot(index='Group', columns='col', values='val').rename_axis(columns=None)
    
 
    
    return userListing_DF 

dir1 =  filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r", initialdir="/", title="select file",
                                       filetypes=(("text files", "*.txt"), ("all files", "*.*")))

dir2 = filedialog.askopenfile(mode="rb", initialdir="/", title="Select the second file",
                                       filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*")))

pre_Processing(dir1,dir2)
```

The issue I'm having is I'm not sure how to call the df that was created in the Pre_processing_File.py so I can name it and then save it as an excel.
I'm aware that there isn't a need for 2 files in this case but there is a method to my madness so any help for this scenario would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does pre_Processing do? can you make it return a df?

Comment: @doctorlove it takes in a txt file and does some file manipulation and creates a pandas DF called "df". I now want to call this df into the naming.py file and export it as an excel file

Comment: Add `return df` to the end of the function, and call it like `df = pre_Processing()` (or with any needed parameters), then you will have the `df` after the function

Comment: @doctorlove Great thanks. I'm getting somewhere. just one more question as I'm getting an error. In my pre_Processing function I have 2 arguments pre_Processing(dir1,dir2). How would I call them as I'm getting an error saying dir is not defined. Thanks

Comment: Post the code?, because it's hard to guess - also where is the error - here, where you call it or in the pre process function?

Comment: @doctorlove I have included the code of the second file and updated the code of the first (note I did leave some of the code out for the pre_processing as it is work related)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do (since this is just part of your code), so some of my changes might conflict with other parts of your code. But given what you want to do, I would do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from Pre_Processing_File import pre_Processing

def naming():
    df = pre_Processing()
    df.to_excel('The filename you want to use.xlsx')
    
    
naming()
```

Pre_Processing File:

```
## Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame # Note that this is not really conventional...
from tkinter import *
  
# import filedialog module
from tkinter import filedialog

def pre_Processing():
    # Ask user for the dir1 and dir2 (what are you doing with dir2?)
    dir1 =  filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r", initialdir="/", title="select file",
                                       filetypes=(("text files", "*.txt"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    dir2 = filedialog.askopenfile(mode="rb", initialdir="/", title="Select the second file",
                                       filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*")))        
    ## Read in the single long column, and then form a group indicator by seeing where the value is '[User]'. Then separate the 
    ## column labels and values, with a str.split and join back to your DataFrame. Finally pivot to your desired shape.
    
    userListing_DF = pd.read_csv(dir1, sep='\n', header=None)

    userListing_DF['Group'] = userListing_DF[0].eq('[User]').cumsum()
    userListing_DF = userListing_DF[userListing_DF[0].ne('[User]')]  # No longer need these rows

    userListing_DF = pd.concat([userListing_DF, userListing_DF[0].str.split('=', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'col', 1: 'val'})],
                               axis=1)

    userListing_DF = userListing_DF.pivot(index='Group', columns='col', values='val').rename_axis(columns=None)
            
    return userListing_DF
```

If you need `dir1` and `dir2` in another part of your code, I would probably create a different function in `Pre_Processing_File` where you run the GUI and ask for the directory names for `dir1` and `dir2` and `return` to your main script for further use...

Comment: Great thanks @nielshenkens. I'm getting the following error whoever AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'to_excel'.

Comment: Without seeing the code you have, it's hard to guess, but it sounds like you have a df set to a function, instead of calling it

Comment: Yes, because if I try to do userListing_DF.head() when I call in the function it does not work

Comment: Then probably somewhere in `pre_Processing()` you are (erroneously) converting `userListing_DF` to a function instead of a DataFrame. Print the type of `df` in `naming()` before you call `df.to_excel(...)` and it will not be a Pandas DataFrame...

Comment: When I type userListing_DF.dtypes it doesn't return anything

Comment: That is a different thing (that shows the column types of a DataFrame). use `print(type(df))`.

Comment: @nielshenkens, its a <class 'function'>, however if I check it in the pre processing file it returns <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: So `print(type(userListing_DF))` gives you <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> right before `return userListing_DF`?

Comment: And you used `df = pre_Processing()` exactly within `naming()`?

Comment: @NielsHenkensit's working!! ABSOLUTELY Fantastic, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make `pre_Processing()` `return` the dataframe it creates and then use this inside of `naming()` to get the dataframe like:

```
def naming():
from Pre_Processing_File import pre_Processing

    df = pre_Processing(dir1,dir2)
```

Note that, in case Pre_processing_File.py is located in another directory than naming.py, you will have to update `dir1` and `dir2` accordingly during the assignment in `naming()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the code at the bottom of the preprocessing file to your naming function:

```
import pandas as pd

def naming():
    import Pre_Processing_File
    from Pre_Processing_File import pre_Processing
    
    dir1 =  filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r", initialdir="/", title="select file",
                       filetypes=(("text files", "*.txt"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    dir2 = filedialog.askopenfile(mode="rb", initialdir="/", title="Select the second file",
                       filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    DormantAcc = pre_Processing(dir1,dir2)
    # then to_excel here or whatever else you want to do
    
naming()
```

Comment: No luck either, I had tried that earlier. error is **NameError: name 'dir1' is not defined**

Comment: On which line (of which file)?

Comment: line 135 of Pre_processing file - pre_Processing(dir1,dir2)

Comment: I can't see all of your code - but I suggested moving the `dir1 =` and `dir2 =` and the call to the function into the naming file. Sounds like you may have left them behind?

Comment: I have moved them to the naming file and removed them from the pre processing file but I still get the error. I think the issue is I still have dir1, and dir 2 when I define the function in the pre processing file, If I remove them from there also it errors on this line userListing_DF = pd.read_csv(dir1, sep='\n', header=None)

Comment: You shouldn't remove dir1 and dir2 from the definition of `pre_Processing(dir1, dir2):`. If you run `naming()`, do you correctly get the filedialogs for dir1 and dir2? Did you also move `from tkinter import filedialog` to the naming file?

Comment: Hi @NielsHenkens, I'm currently trying 2 solutions, your one (please see comment above) and doctorlove. No unfortunatelyI don't get the file dialogs for doctorlove solution

Comment: This question has got out of hand. Can you make a new question, and show us code that exhibits the same problem, so when you mention line numbers we know where?